# Is there diference between black and white nylon in guitar strings?

Tags: guitar, strings, classical-guitar

Is there difference between black and white nylon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, Black (and sometimes Red) nylon strings have more of a treble/high end sound and are more distinctive in tone than the classic nylon.

**Sources:**

[Wisegeek article on classical strings](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-should-i-know-about-classical-guitar-strings.htm)

[JustStrings overview of classical strings](http://www.juststrings.com/classicalguitar.html)

Comment: Do you have any idea how the densities of different materials compare?  For example, would if black string and clear string of a certain diameter were set to the same tension, which would produce a higher pitch?